# How to add multiple hidden items into a create form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have a form where my users can choose a date and a spot to create a new reservation.
Every reservation can have several spots.

```
class Reservation < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :spotations
    has_many :spots, :through => :spotations
end 
class Spotation < ActiveRecord::Base
        belongs_to :reservation
        belongs_to :spot
end
class Spot < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :spotations
    has_many :reservations, :through => :spotations
end
```

For now I give my user a select_list to choose ONE spot.
Only the available spots are displayed in that list. (only the spots that are not in reservations that day for that item)

```
<%= f.collection_select :spot_ids, @availablespots, :id, :name, {:prompt => true}, {class: "form-control  spot_selection", id:"reservation_spot_ids", name:"reservation[spot_ids]", required:"required" } %>
```

Everything works well.

But I made my model to accept several spots:
I want to book the spot chosen by the user AND the spot before that automatically (for travel time).

I have no idea how to do that in my controller.

All my spots are ordered by id. (1 to 20) and if the user choose the available spot id=4, i want to book id=3 also.

Someone has an idea ?
Thank you,

Comment: in the create action, you find the spot n-1 and add it to the model.

Comment: Thx for your reply. How can I access my :spot_ids params (hash) once it is sent to the creation process ? (to get n-1) and then how can i put back the spot (n-1 that I found) into the creation process again ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are thinking in more difficult way..
the 'n' is the number which a user chose.
then, the 'n-1' can be created in your controller.

Always see all the passed params before you manipulate, 
use `<% logger.debug "PARAM CHECKER: #{params.inspect}" %>`

after you contemplate how to get what you want from that hash-type parameter, you can create `n-1`.

Comment: Thx for your answer. I understand what is n and n-1. 
But I have several problems:
First, how can I get that Hash param, then I know how to get n-1 and finally how to inject that new n-1 value into the hash to be sent before the creation of my issue.

Comment: @Devlesch: you just call 'params'.